# Programming the ATMega324A-PU through the Arduino IDE

Tags: c++, arduino

How do you set the board (chip) type? How do you set the fuses? All in the (and to use the) Arduino IDE?

Answer (score 0):

You find or write a core for the chip, and you install it into the IDE. Since you need a programmer regardless, just tell the IDE to use that instead of trying to use its UART.